# Wrapping certain characters around a tag in sql table function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing a simple select which is bringing back 1 row, with 3 columns as such:

```
select @NotesMain1  = c.NOTE1,  
           @NotesMain2  = c.NOTE2, 
           @NotesMain3  = c.NOTE3,      
    from tblTEST
```

And i am assigning them to a parameter, each column contains a string beginning with a number then dot. E.g. column one contains "1. ~~~~" column 2 contains "2. ~~~~~" then column 3 contains "3.~~~~~~"

Using regex i was able to find all numbers then full stop using:

```
([0-9]\.)
```

I am trying to find all these occurances with a number then dot at the beginning, and wrap them with a "`<p>`" & "`</p>`"

as such column 1 will contain "`<p> 1. </p> ~~~`"

Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would also be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REPLACE(col1,'"','<p>') justforshow
 ,STUFF(  REPLACE(col1,'"','<p>'),LEN(col1)+3,0,'/') col1solution
 ,STUFF(  REPLACE(col2,'"','<p>'),LEN(col2)+3,0,'/') col2solution
 ,STUFF(  REPLACE(col3,'"','<p>'),LEN(col3)+3,0,'/') col3solution

  FROM
    (   SELECT  '"1.hello"' AS Col1
              , '"2.28311"' AS Col2
              , '"3.23"'    AS Col3
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  '"1.hello"' AS Col1
              , '"2.28311"' AS Col2
              , '"3.23"'    AS Col3)aList
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect thank you! :) what i was trying to do though, was to wrap the P tags around the number and the dot only .. not the whole contents.. sorry for the confusion!